# Why getColumnIndex in sqlite return number of column in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, select, indexing

I have a table with this info:
    i create table.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS income (id_income INTEGER 
PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, id_category INT(20), id_account INT(20),
Year INT(5), month INT(5), day INT(5) ,pay DOUBLE(20));");
```

then i insert a row in this table:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO
    income(id_category,id_account,Year,month,day,pay)  VALUES
    (1,1,2013,1,1,678);");
```

Then i select * from my table,

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM income ";       
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);         
cursor.moveToFirst();

int count = cursor.getCount();
if(count>0){
    for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {
         int temp_acc1;
         int temp_cat;
         temp_acc1=(cursor1.getColumnIndex("id_account"));   
         temp_cat=(cursor1.getColumnIndex("id_category"));
    }
}
```

But when i log temp_acc1 or temp_cat, it returns number of column.
For example temp_acc1 returns 3 // actually returns 1
or  temp_cat returns 2 // actually returns 1
or if i use temp_year=cursor1.getColumnIndex("Year") it returns 5.//// actually returns 2013

What should i do?

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this kind of code`cursor1.getColumnIndex("Year")` to this `cursor1.getInteger(cursor1.getColumnIndex("Year"))`. So it will return the value

Comment: just use:cursor1.getInt(cursor1.getColumnIndex("Year"))